# Do the scriptures mention of a particular period of the year more suitable for birth of progeny or for copulation?

Tags: scripture, vedas, sex

As the question says, do the scriptures mention of a particular period of the year more suitable for birth of progeny or for copulation? Any Rutus/months/weather which is better suited?

Comment: Can I ask why you are interested in this?

Comment: @Wikash_ For my knowledge